# Sorting by type in Project Explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I recently upgraded to Helio SR2 and the sort order for the package explorer is now sorting by name no matter the type.  Is there any way to specify the sort order?

### Example

- JAX-WS Web Service
- Deployment Descriptor
- Java Resources
- pom.xml (File)
- src (Folder)

  - main (Folder)
  - java (Folder)
  - webapp (Folder)

    - a.jsp (File)
    - b (Folder)
    - c.jsp (File)
    - WEB-INF (Folder)
    - z.jsp (File)

In the example above, the files and folders are not sorted by type and then sorted by name (like in Windows Explorer).

### Expected

- JAX-WS Web Service
- Deployment Descriptor
- Java Resources
- src (Folder)

  - main (Folder)
  - java (Folder)
  - webapp (Folder)

    - b (Folder)
    - WEB-INF (Folder)
    - a.jsp (File)
    - c.jsp (File)
    - z.jsp (File)
- pom.xml (File)

Previous versions were sorting it this way - I'm just not sure how to set it back.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Double check you are not using "Project Explorer", it sorts alphabetically. BUT,

- "Package Explorer" sorts files the way you want.
- "Navigator" also sorts the way your asking and will show hidden files in OSX and Win folders.

You can access these views via Window->Show View->Other

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I was using the "Project Explorer" view instead of the "Package Explorer".  Thank you!

Comment: I've two installations of Eclipse in two computers. In one installation Project Explorer is showing files sorted by type and in other it is showing files sorted alphabetically. Why is that?

Comment: In Eclipse Kepler by default it comes with the sorting way of `Package Explorer` for `Project Explorer`.

Comment: I do not see any options for changing the sorting order in Eclipse 2022.03

Answer (score 24):

I did it in some other way as the given solution does not worked for me. I went to the customize view option as shown in

[image: Customize View]

and then wen to Content tab as shown in

[image]

and then unchecked the "Resources" check box.

Comment: Can somebody explain me what are "Resources" in "Conent" tab and why they behave so odd as described above?

Comment: I tried this method, and it works except that I can no longer rename some of my files in the project. However, if I uncheck the "Deployed Resourecs" instead of "Resources", I can rename my files and get folders and files sorted as expected.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Package Explorer or Navigator seem to be better options.

Answer (score 3):

you can uncheck the "Deployed resources" in custom view!

[image: Customize View]

[image: uncheck]