# How to change the file sort in Eclipse (Kepler) project

Tags: eclipse

I've been starting using Eclipse Kepler and I found that the sort of files in my project is disordered. Please refer to the screenshot:[image]

The files are sort by file name instead of file type. I expect the folders come to the top. Can someone help me to this updated?

Comment: Which view are you in?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen I'm in Project view.

Comment: Maybe try Package Explorer view.

Comment: refer to this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352431/sorting-by-type-in-project-explorer-in-eclipse/18784485#18784485][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352431/sorting-by-type-in-project-explorer-in-eclipse/18784485#18784485

Comment: the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352431/sorting-by-type-in-project-explorer-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

In Navigator View, you can change the sort order.

[image: Sort order in Navigator View]

Comment: Yes, it works in Navigator view. But I prefer to use it in Project Explorer view. Is there any chance to change the sort?

Comment: Are you using Maven WTP integration?