# Sort by number size in Eclipse Android

Tags: eclipse

Recently i had to import my image item list, in windows it's ordered correctly by the number size:

**Example:** 1-0, 2-0, 3-0, 4-0, 5-0, 6-0, 7-0, 8-0, 9-0, 10-0, 11-0 ... etc

When i put these files into my assets they went crazy alike:

1-0, 10-0, 2-0, 2-1, 21-0, 22-0, 23-0, 3-0, 30-0, etc.

Image here link here: http://i.gyazo.com/a429e959b51958645ccb58ce44093426.png

I'm extremely sorry if this problem has been already posted but i couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can probably put all the files under version control, then add your image files, then check which file has changed and edit this file manually.

Answer (score 1):

They sorted as strings, not as numbers.

Comment: Is there any way to sort it as numbers?

Comment: It depends what view you are using. Try this http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/470249/

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352431/sorting-by-type-in-project-explorer-in-eclipse . 

It's not working at all after i drag my items into assets.